# Dynamic if exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to check the condition if the index present in the table then fire stored procedure else other condition must be proceed.

**Example**:

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
    BEGIN
         execute spTest1
    END
 ELSE
    BEGIN
         execute spTest2
    END
```

**Note**: In the above script the `@TableName` will be pass dynamically in the format of within single quote for example `'tableName'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the SQL, apart from a missing close bracket on the end of the `EXISTS` line:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName))
    BEGIN
         execute spTest1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
         execute spTest2
    END
```

This will work, but you might always find an index without filtering the data in some way. You might want to be more specific about the type of indexes you are searching for as SQL will create some default indexes. For example if you create a table with a primary key, a clustered index will be created for you.

If no primary key is added you will usually have a **[HEAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx)** type index, so this might be the type of index you are looking to filter.

If you run this against your target database, you will see the indexes that exist:

```
select st.name, st.object_id, si.name, si. index_id, si.type, si.type_desc
from sys.tables st
inner join sys.indexes si on si.object_id = st.object_id
```

In order to filter `HEAP` indexes, you could exclude clustered/non-clustered indexes you could filter by `sys.indexes.index_id`:

- Heap: `index_id = 0`
- Clustered: `index_id = 1`
- Non Clustered: `index_id = 2`